# Merging columns with same same using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, merge, pandas-groupby

I have the following data in CSV file:

```
time   conc   time   conc   time    conc   time   conc
1:00    10    5:00   11     9:00    55     13:00   1
2:00    13    6:00   8      10:00   6      14:00   4 
3:00    9     7:00   7      11:00   8      15:00   3
4:00    8     8:00   1      12:00   11     16:00   8
```

And I just wanted to merge them together as:

```
time   conc  
1:00   10
2:00   13
3:00   9
4:00   8
...
16:00  8
```

I've got more than 1000 columns, but I'm new to pandas. So just wondering how I can achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to cut the dataframe in two-column slices, then re-combine using pd.concat() after renaming.
First load the dataframe normally:

```
df = pd.read_csv('time_conc.csv')
df
```

Which looks something like the below. Notice that pd.read_csv() has added a suffix to the duplicate column names:

```
    time    conc    time.1  conc.1  time.2  conc.2  time.3  conc.3
0   1:00    10      5:00    11      9:00    55      13:00   1
1   2:00    13      6:00    8       10:00   6       14:00   4
2   3:00    9       7:00    7       11:00   8       15:00   3
3   4:00    8       8:00    1       12:00   11      16:00   8
```

Then slice using pd.DataFrame.iloc:

```
total_columns = len(df.columns)
columns_per_set = 2

column_sets = [df.iloc[:,set_start:set_start + columns_per_set].copy() for set_start in range(0, total_columns, columns_per_set)]
```

`column_sets` is now a list holding each pair of duplicate columns as a separate dataframe. Next, loop through the list to rename the columns back to the original:

```
for s in column_sets:
    s.columns = ['time', 'conc']
```

This modifies each two-column dataframe in place so that their column names match.
Finally, use pd.concat() to combine them by matching the column axis:

```
new_df = pd.concat(column_sets, axis=0, sort=False)
new_df
```

Which gives you the full two columns:

```
    time    conc
0   1:00    10
1   2:00    13
2   3:00    9
3   4:00    8
0   5:00    11
1   6:00    8
2   7:00    7
3   8:00    1
0   9:00    55
1   10:00   6
2   11:00   8
3   12:00   11
0   13:00   1
1   14:00   4
2   15:00   3
3   16:00   8
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your file has duplicated column names, Pandas will add suffixes. The DataFrame header by default will be like ['time', 'conc', 'time.1', 'conc.1', 'time.2', 'conc.2', 'time.3', 'conc.3' ...]

Assuming that the separator of your CSV file is a comma:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/your/file.csv', sep=',')
total_n = len(df.columns)

lst = []
for x in range(int(total_n / 2 )):
    if x == 0:
        cols = ['time', 'conc']
    else:
        cols = ['time'+'.'+str(x), 'conc'+'.'+str(x)]
    df_sub = df[cols]  #Slice two columns each time
    df_sub.columns = ['time', 'conc']  #Slices should have the same column names
    lst.append(df_sub)
df = pd.concat(lst)  #Concatenate all the objects
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `df` is a DataFrame with the csv file data you can try the following:

```
# rename columns if needed
df.columns = ["time", "conc"]*(df.shape[1]//2)
# concatenate pairs of adjacent columns
pd.concat([df.iloc[:, [i, i+1]] for i in range(0, df.shape[1], 2)])
```

It gives:

```
     time conc
0    1:00  10
1    2:00  13
2    3:00   9
3    4:00   8
0    5:00  11
..    ...  ..
3   12:00  11
0   13:00   1
1   14:00   4
2   15:00   3
3   16:00   8
```